# Sharing code between Android and Windows Mobile

Tags: android, windows-mobile

I'm doing some initial research on smart phone development, and I noticed that Android and Windows Mobile both support c++ for application development.  I was curious if anyone had any experience trying to manage shared files between both Android and Windows Mobile, and to what extent that code can be shared?  e.g. no user interface can be shared, but web service and business logic classes can be shared, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak to the WinMo side of things, but on the Android side you should really really really avoid using native code for anything except performance-critical processing algorithms. JNI/NDK stuff does not play nicely with the normal Dalvik lifecycle and can be a source of all sorts of ugly unpleasant bugs and memory leaks. From what I understand there also aren't on-board NDK libraries for more complex high-level functionality like HTTP (just more basic/performance-oriented libs like libz and OpenGL), so you'd probably have to compile that stuff and ship it with the app as well. I would definitely not recommend coding your web service classes in C++, even if it's technically possible; it'll be less buggy and nicer to write C#/Java and you should be able to make mostly the same architectural decisions for consistency.

That said, if you have a performance-critical bit of image processing code or the like, it actually can be fairly straightforward to get that working across Android to other platforms (I've seen it done quite well with some image-processing C code used in an iPhone app and then used via the NDK in an Android app).

Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) on the NDK for details on what it can (and can't) do, and see similar SO threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301257/can-i-make-a-rather-native-c-app-with-android).

Comment: Agreed.  Except for performance-critical stuff, I wouldn't use C++ on WinMo either.  Basically you need two separate code bases for the two platforms.