# Is Android development in C/C++ faster than Java?

Tags: java, android, c

I have looked around and was unable to find any questions regarding this exact question. I did find some similar questions but not exactly what I want know.

If you develop an Android application in C/C++, will there be a (substantial) speed difference when compared to developing the same application in Java?

Comment: Development speed? Or application performance? (If you are who your nickname claims to be, you probably know best ;-) )

Comment: application speed/performance :)

Comment: Going for C/C++ sacrifices portability (although precious little is non-atom hardware)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#choosing):

> The NDK will not benefit most applications. As a developer, you need
>   to balance its benefits against its drawbacks; notably, **using native
>   code does not result in an automatic performance increase**, but always
>   increases application complexity. In general, you should only use
>   native code if it is essential to your application, not just because
>   you prefer to program in C/C++.

The NDK was intended to be used in performance-critical situations only.

You can however create a whole application with C/C++ but only if the device runs Android 2.3 or later: [Can I make a rather native C++ app with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301257/can-i-make-a-rather-native-c-app-with-android)