# Object tracking using android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, opencv

I want to create an android app where a live camera stream captures obstacles on the ground and issues warnings to the user. This is intended as an application for the visually impaired.

I'm at a loss to understand what technologies are most suitable for this as I have no previous experience in image processing. I looked through some OpenCV examples, but they didn't provide me with much insight as to where to start the project from.

What I need to know is;

- Any tutorials that might help me to get started on the project (should I start with basic image processing?)
- Should I learn C++, since I only know java and C#?
- What technologies that could be used in the project. (Is it possible to achieve something like this through Augmented Reality etc..)
- Any previous projects/ tutorials/ examples that tries to achieve android image processing

If you could provide me with some answers to any of the above points I'd be much grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea/requirement is rather "special", so I don't think there are any tutorials to archive exactly this. I would start by reading the source of other apps that use image processing, for example [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/).

Augmented reality could be used to show these "warnings", but wouldn't help you with the image-processing part. Here is a Book on [Augmented Reality on Android.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143023945X)

For the C++ part I'll refer to my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8118718/717341).